# proper way to edit drupal_page_header()

Tags: hooks

I can't find a hook for overrideing `drupal_page_header()` in bootstrap.inc and it doesn't feel right to make changes in bootstrap.inc.

Is there another other way that I'm missing?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to change the header('cache-control') but I did it in template_page_preprocess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you goal is only to change the `Cache-Control` you can use [drupal_add_http_header()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7). According the documentation this function allow you override an existing header. If you add it in you template.php you'll able to change the header without patch the core function.